# Break a while loop using external event

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop, workflow-foundation, state-machine

I have a while loop in a windows service which runs for some x times and inititate x phone calls after reading them from some file . Now if i want to make a user interface which gives an option to stop the phone calls i.e. break the while loop even before it is completed. How shall i do it ?

Lets suppose i have a function .

```
DialCalls(x)
{
  for(int i= 0 ; i<x ; i++)
  {
    // Initiate call
  }
}
```

There can be 2,3 DialCalls functions running at the same time in different threads as i have done threading in the application as well . So basically what is best way to break the loop from a webpage maybe.

Comment: For the folks suggesting `volatile`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) cancellation ( new in .net 4):

```
[Fact]
public void StartAndCancel()
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    var tasks = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 2)
                          .Select(i => Task.Run(() => Dial(token), token))
                          .ToArray(); // start dialing on two threads
    Thread.Sleep(200); // give the tasks time to start
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    Assert.Throws<AggregateException>(() => Task.WaitAll(tasks));
    Assert.True(tasks.All(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled));
}

public void Dial(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.WriteLine("Called from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx
The task swallows exceptions so there is some cleanup to to, maybe as IDisposable?
[About task exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx)

Comment: this is a good answer (so +1), but you can improve it by including a few relevant snippets from the article.

Answer (score 4):

You can write an if-statement inside your loop, to poll the status of the external event.

For example, you could have a flag:

`bool break_out = false;`

And in your external event, you set the break_out flag to true:

`break_out = true;`

Now in your loop, you can have:

```
DialCalls(x)
{
  for(int i= 0 ; i<x ; i++)
  {
    // Initiate call

    if (break_out) {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an event supporting cancellation:

```
public event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> Call;
```

If subscriber exists and cancels it, don't call:

```
while (true)
{
    var e = new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs();
    if (Call != null)
    {
        Call(this, e);
    }
    if (!e.Cancel)
    {
        // Initiate call
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!_shouldStop) { /* work in progress */ }
```

and in the `Stop()` method which should be on the same worker class the bool variable must be set as true.

Also, if there is any waiters (like [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)) they must be `.Set();`.

Answer (score 0):

By using a variable telling when to break.

```
private bool _cancel;

void DialCalls(...)
{
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        ...
        if (_cancel) break;
        ....
    }
}

private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancel = true;
}
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<x && !_cancel; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a global variable which is volatile

```
public static volatile bool stop;    
stop=False;

DialCalls(x)
{
  for(int i= 0 ; i<x && !stop ; i++)
  {
    // Initiate call
  }
}

On Button Click => stop =True;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a endpoint on the service that accept a message that toggles a global/static boolean (or some other) variable, and have the loop inside `DialCalls` check said variable at the start of each iteration. It won't interrupt any phone calls currently in progress, but I'm betting you don't want the service to hang up in the middle of the call, just don't move on to the next one. This would interrupt for all threads as well; just make sure to make the variable itself is thread-safe (e.g., use `volatile` keyword).